Find the point of intersection of an annuity and an investment
We were completing some classwork for Annuities and finding the Sum of a G.P for simple situations as well as finding the time take for an annuity to reach a given value.
Given the context we wanted to see, if you start saving $10,000 a year how long would you have to save to purchase a house and we modelled the growth of the value of the house.
A house is worth $150,000 and appreciates at 7.5% P.A compounded annually and the Future Value can be found with:
$150000(1.075)^n$
The annuity can be represented by the equations
$135000(1.08^n - 1)$
For what value of n are they equal? We have tried solving making the equations equal to each other and solve.
We have got as far as:
$150000(1.075)^{n} = 1235000(1.08^n -1)$
$10/9 (1.075)^{n} = 1.08^{n} -1$
We can find the solution of approximately 36 by trial and error and graphing on Desmos but we are looking for an algebraic solution.
We have been doing logs and Sum of GP and we thought we could solve simultaneously but we're stuck at the above.
We tried substituting let a = 1.075 and b = 1.08
giving:
$10a^n - 9b^{n} = -9$
but the different powers of n has us stuck. We think we could be able to change the base of the powers???
Sorry for first post

As an FYI: MSE is not a "do my (home)work for me" site. Such posts (e.g. "PSQs") are often in poor taste, downvoted, & closed; we expect users to actively put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. Also: this is helpful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 can help find past questions.

Hi, this isn't a do my homework question. I have added context and attempts we have made.
